# Как извлечь значение ключа из списка?

Tags: python-3.x

Как извлечь значение `order_id` и присвоить его переменной?
Делается запрос `activeorder`, ответ:

```
{'USD_RUB': [{'order_id': '1053805089', 'created': '1532857339', 'type': 'sell', 'pair': 'USD_RUB', 'quantity': '3.992', 'price': '67', 'amount': '267.464'}, {'order_id': '1053732621', 'created': '1532855318', 'type': 'buy', 'pair': 'USD_RUB', 'quantity': '4', 'price': '52', 'amount': '208'}]}
```

Передаю переменной `typev = activeorder['USD_RUB']` и получаю ответ.

Как из ответа ниже, выудить значение ордерид и присвоить его переменной, где присутствует `type buy`?

```
[{'order_id': '1053805089', 'created': '1532857339', 'type': 'sell', 'pair': 'USD_RUB', 'quantity': '3.992', 'price': '67', 'amount': '267.464'}, 
{'order_id': '1053732621', 'created': '1532855318', 'type': 'buy', 'pair': 'USD_RUB', 'quantity': '4', 'price': '52', 'amount': '208'}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list_ = [{'order_id': '1053805089', 'created': '1532857339', 'type': 'sell', 'pair': 'USD_RUB', 'quantity': '3.992', 'price': '67', 'amount': '267.464'},
         {'order_id': '1053732621', 'created': '1532855318', 'type': 'buy', 'pair': 'USD_RUB', 'quantity': '4', 'price': '52', 'amount': '208'}]

result_dic = [dic['order_id'] for dic in list_ if dic['type'] == 'buy']
result = result_dic[0]

print(result)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 1053732621
> ```

---

**Объяснение выражения `[dic['order_id'] for dic in list_ if dic['type'] == 'buy']`:**

Это так называемое *списковое включение* или *абстракция
списков* (list comprehension). Ваш список `list_` является списком *словарей* - мы будем проходить его, обозначая частный словарь как `dic`:

```
[............... for dic in list_ ......................]
```

Но нас интересуют только те из них, у которых значение `'buy'` для ключа `'type'`, т.е. у которых `dic['type'] == 'buy'`:

```
[............... for dic in list_ if dic['type'] == 'buy']
```

Но а теперь нас не интересуют эти словари как *цёлое*, а только *значения их ключа `'order_id'`*, т.е. `dic['order_id']` - именно *эти* мы включим в результатный список:

```
[dic['order_id'] for dic in list_ if dic['type'] == 'buy']
```

Comment: а можно поподробней расписать что есть что [dic['order_id'] for dic in list_ if dic['type'] == 'buy']   .в инете почитал но там простые примеры, а "значение из списка в списке через список" не попались! и можно ответ [{'order_id': '1053805089', 'created': '1532857339', 'type': 'sell', 'pair': 'USD_RUB', 'quantity': '3.992', 'price': '67', 'amount': '267.464'}, 
{'order_id': '1053732621', 'created': '1532855318', 'type': 'buy', 'pair': 'USD_RUB', 'quantity': '4', 'price': '52', 'amount': '208'}]

Comment: переделать в словари словарь,сделать два словаря(а если ответ с большими даннымитам три-четыре ид(или правильней вложенных словарей)?я к тому что как из начальных полученных знаний придти к такому [dic['order_id'] for dic in list_ if dic['type'] == 'buy']

Answer (score 1):

```
activeorder = {
  'USD_RUB': [
    {'order_id': '1053805089',
     'created': '1532857339',
     'type': 'sell',
     'pair': 'USD_RUB',
     'quantity': '3.992',
     'price': '67',
     'amount': '267.464'},
    {'order_id': '1053732621',
    'created': '1532855318',
    'type': 'buy',
    'pair': 'USD_RUB',
    'quantity': '4',
    'price': '52',
    'amount': '208'}
  ]
}
item = list(filter(lambda x: x['type'] == 'buy', activeorder['USD_RUB']))[0]
print(item['order_id'])
```